# Cannot use end() to pop the sets back off of the stack in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've noticed that the .end() cannot get back the old set of jquery elements, if I set jQuery elements in find().

According to jquery document http://api.jquery.com/find/ . It should accept jQuery object. Is it a bug? Or something I should know ? Thank you very much.

```
<section>
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">
    This is my DIV ... <span id="p-text"></span>
</div>
</section>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){

var $m = $('#myDiv');
var $t = $('#p-text');

// this will show myDiv
$m.find('#p-text').text('blabla').end().show();

// this will not show myDiv
$m.find($t).text('blabla2').end().show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense, you would never use `$m.find($t)` because you already have `$t`. You're better off doing $t.text("blabla"); $m.show();

Comment: Yes. I know I can just $t.text('blabla'). In this question, I just want to keep it as simple as possible to learn the difference between using jQuery object or selector string in find(). I don't know why they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-EDIT:

The difference is between `$m.find(<string selector>)` and `$m.find(<jquery object>);`

#### Assumptions

- The `end()` function return an object called `prevObject` (this is a not-documented public property of jquery stack), stored in returned jquery stack.
- This property is set, indirectly, in function like `find` and `filter`
- The method `find` behaves differently depending on type of argument (`string` or `jquery Object`)

#### what happens

- if the argument is `<String selector>` then it store the current jquery object in this `prevObject` property.
- if the argument is  `<jquery object>` then store the RETURNED stack in this property.

indeed:

```
$m.find('#p-text') // return a stack with element <span> and prevObject = $m
.text('blabla') // change simply the text
.end() // return the stack stored in prevObject (ie $m)
.show(); // show the current stack (ie $m)
```

and it works because `$m` is the element with `display:none`

in the second case:

```
$m.find($t) // return a stack with <span> element BUT the prevObject property is the $t element
.text('blabla2') // again change the text
.end() // return the stack stored in prevObject (IE $t now!!)
.show(); // show the current stack (ie $t)
```

and it does NOT works because the `$t` element is only a child of hidden element.

#### Why?

The `find` method use internally the method `jQuery( selector ).filter` if the `selector` is a jquery object. Here the piece of source code

```
if ( typeof selector !== "string" ) {
    return jQuery( selector ).filter(function() { // <---- here
        for ( i = 0, l = self.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            if ( jQuery.contains( self[ i ], this ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This call return a stack with prevObject filled with `jQuery( selector )` instead of original stack. In your case the prevObject is the jquery object `$t` instead of `$m`.

I think that's a bug resulted from a objectless use of jquery library (your code has no sense because you should write simply `$t.text('blabla2').show()`)

Comment: Hi.. chumkiu. thank you for your explanation. In fact, I've also tried to add .end() after the .end(). However, I only get empty jQuery object. It seems if I use jQuery object or dom element in .find(), it will destroy the previous objects. ( It looks like the $m is replaced by $t in the filter stack )

Comment: @BenP.P.Tung it's because jquery .end() search the objects in different stack.

Comment: @BenP.P.Tung i've edited the answer because it was inaccurate (and wrong for some points). Now it will be more clear